# Why App Size Over 100mb can still be downloaded over cellular?

Tags: ios, app-store

I found Facebook app in the app store is around 160mb, but didn't get size warning prompt when downloading it over cellular. The Linkedin app is 221mb, I did get the prompt when downloading it. I thought the app size limitation to be downloaded over cellular is 100mb, but seems doesn't apply? Why?